# Removing data from JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, filtering

I have a JavaScript object `info` and when I do `_(info).values()` in the firebug console, I get.

```
[Object {}, Object { a=6, b=7, more...}, Object { a=2, b=21, more...}, Object {}, Object { a=2, b=9, more...}]
```

So how can I remove items with `Object {}`  from the above `info` object by using underscore filter or any other efficient techniques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underscore

```
_.pick(info, _.filter(_.keys(info), function(key) {
    return _.keys(info[key]).length > 0;
}));
```

Abstracted into a function

```
_.filterObject = function(obj, callback) {
    return _.pick(obj, _.filter(_.keys(obj), callback))
};

_.filterObject(info, function(key) {
    return _keys(info[key]).length > 0;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/2kf8C/1/

**Explanation**

- `_.pick` returns a new object with only the passed in properties
- `_.filter` returns just the properties we want, the ones that have keys

Note that this returns a new object, it doesn't modify the original

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I did not realize that I could actually nest it is such a way. I was using reject, so I guess it works on lists, but not on objects. Btw, if we talk about efficiency or processing time, which method do you think is better? Let's say the data elements are in range of millions.

Comment: @user3670175 I can't speak for performance, because it depends on how you're using it. Your best bet is to test it yourself using http://jsperf.com/ and report any questions/findings as another question here. Please accept this answer if it correctly answers your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript solution:

```
var ob={a:{}, b:{ a:6}, c: { a:2}};
function removeEmpty(ob){
    for(var i in ob){
        if(typeof(ob[i])=='object'){
            var keys=Object.keys(ob[i]);
            if(keys.length==0) delete ob[i];
        }
    }
}
removeEmpty(ob);
console.log(ob); // b:{a:6}, c{a:2}
```

Comment: This works well but was looking for something in underscore, thanks for this.

Comment: Big difference between this and underscore is that the underscore solution creates a new object, this modifies the existing